# How good it is to have an ElasticSearch Cluster for read-only database?

Tags: firebase, elasticsearch

I have an e-commerce application based on Firebase backend, and I am using Firebase Cloud Functions to submit data to Elasticsearch for the sake of advanced search! Now that firebase reads costs a lot I am relying on ES(Elasticsearch) to read data such as products/users etc... So let's say that the reads operations are taking place on ES while write operations on Firebase.

How much this architecture is good? I mean is it good to rely on ES as primary database for read-only?

Comment: what type of queries are these ? Free text ,  reverse indexed or are they SKU specific ? ES is a great choice for text and advanced use cases. Again choice of DB's are very opinionated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems in this approach with proper Elasticsearch cluster configuration. Elasticsearch is very good for reading. I have projects that are using Elasticsearch as main read DB for years (more than 5 years). This is also e-commerce type projects.

However, for sure it depends on your load. If load is really big, Elasticsearch can also be expansive and may be will be better idea to add another type of fast cheap storage to handle reads (like DynamoDB in AWS, don't know exact GCP analog).

Comment: can you please share the pricing on how much you paying per month if possible for such cluster? And my other question is that if you are using elastic.co?

Comment: 1. Cloud from elastic.co is one of the best options, as you will use official product with all updates and options. It is stable and super easy to scale. I'm prefer to use it if budget allows. 
2. For small projects without big load - I'm using https://bonsai.io/. It is cheaper but also very good and stable.
3. Some projects are hosted in clouds, like AWS of Azure or GCP, and it make sense to use internal VPC resources to same money on traffic.

Comment: Pricing is also very depends on your load. Plus of managed providers like elastic.co or bonsai.io that you can start with smaller and then just scale up to bigger cluster in case of need without any problems or downtime.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex for your kind response, very helpful...